# How do I show $e_r$ and its first- and second time derivative?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, vectors, maxwell-equations

What does a charge q moving in a circular orbit with a constant velocity (a "rotating charge") and a stationary observer that measures the E field look like? And how do I show $e_r$ and its first- and second time derivative in here?